# Getting a list of companies with dual share classes using cusip

Tags: r, list, sorting

I am a beginner in R, and I have a table that consists of two columns. The first column is the ID. The second column is the label (actually CUSIP in CRSP data). The label is the eight-digit number where the first six digits identify the ID, and the last two-digit may differ by certain attributes of the ID.

I would like to have a list of IDs that has two different labels where one of the two labels ends with a different two-digit number.

for example, if the table looks as follows,

| ID | label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11223330 |
| 1 | 11223341 |
| 2 | 11224430 |
| 3 | 11225530 |
| 3 | 11225531 |
| 4 | 11226630 |
| 5 | 11227730 |
| 5 | 11227753 |

in this case, I hope to see

| ID | label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11223330 |
| 1 | 11223341 |
| 3 | 11225530 |
| 3 | 11225531 |
| 5 | 11227730 |
| 5 | 11227753 |

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've only got these two columns or you have other variables, but not `ID`-`label` pair is repeated you could use this

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L), label = c(11223330L, 
11223341L, 11224430L, 11225530L, 11225531L, 11226630L, 11227730L, 
11227753L)), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")

dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(var3 = 8:1)

dat %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%  
  filter(n() >= 2) 
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>      ID    label  var3
#>   <int>    <int> <int>
#> 1     1 11223330     8
#> 2     1 11223341     7
#> 3     3 11225530     5
#> 4     3 11225531     4
#> 5     5 11227730     2
#> 6     5 11227753     1
```

However, if you've got duplicated `ID`-`label` pairs and other variables that you want to retain and you only want one row per `ID`-`label` pair, you could turn the other variables into list columns:

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L), label = c(11223330L, 
11223341L, 11224430L, 11225530L, 11225531L, 11226630L, 11227730L, 
11227753L)), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
dat <- bind_rows(dat, dat)
dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(var3 = 16:1)

out <- dat %>% 
  group_by(ID, label) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~list(.x))) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 2) 
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'ID'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.

out
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>      ID    label var3     
#>   <int>    <int> <list>   
#> 1     1 11223330 <int [2]>
#> 2     1 11223341 <int [2]>
#> 3     3 11225530 <int [2]>
#> 4     3 11225531 <int [2]>
#> 5     5 11227730 <int [2]>
#> 6     5 11227753 <int [2]>

out$var3
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 16  8
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 15  7
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 13  5
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 12  4
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 10  2
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 9 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much!! I was just wondering what would happen to the code if I do the same thing, but there are three columns, say (1st column= ID, 2nd column = a new variable 'return', and 3rd column = label). My guess is that something in the last row, inside the filter, needs to change and specify that I am dealing with 3rd column in specific. Is this correct?

Comment: @dodobirdy I updated the answer with a couple of other options.